# How to change a base class attribute of a case class

Tags: scala

Take the following code:

```
class A(val i: Int)

case class B(str: String) extends A(1)

val b = B("test")
```

In my scenario I am restricted by the definition of B which cannot be changed. I also wish to avoid reconstructing B as I have many such objects with a lot more attributes than in this example.

Is there any way I can create a new copy of b (using reflection or otherwise) with a new value for i?

Something that would be the equivalent of:

```
val b2 = b.copy(i = 2)
```

NOTE: The question is can it be done? Not what the best programming practice is.

Comment: It's strongly recommended not to have OOP hierarchy for case classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using reflection with something like this:

```
  val b = B("foo")
  val c = b.copy()
  println(b.i) // prints 1
  val field = classOf[A].getDeclaredFields.head
  field.setAccessible(true)
  field.setInt(c, 2)
  println(c.i) // prints 2
```

But beware, this is not just "bad programming practice", but rather *complete breakage of the contract*.

Your declaration `case class B(s: Sting) extends A(1)` promises that *all* instances of `B` will *always* have `i` equal to 1, which is a lie.

Not to mention, fun facts like `b == c` being `true` or `c.copy.i` being 1 etc.
Don't do this.

Comment: I agree that this is really something you shouldn't do, but there is no contract that says that the member `i` of an object of type `B` is always `1`. You would have to make `B` `final` for that to be the case.

Comment: classOf[A].getFields returns an empty array when I test it

Comment: @user79074 Sorry, try `.getDeclaredFields`

Comment: @Tim I meant instances of `B` itself, not of subclasses (but, yeah, technically, you are correct, as subclasses _are_ `B`s too)

Comment: I only mention it because I have been caught out by this is in the past! But the moral of this story is that you should only use `case class` to define simple structures with all the members in the constructor. Anything else is just asking for trouble!

Comment: @Tim even if everything is in the constructor, creating subclasses of a case class is always fun :) Those things should really be `final` automatically. They have forbidden case-to-case inheritance in 2.12, but couldn't go all the way because of some compatibility issues ...

Answer (score 0):

Not if you define `B` that way. But this code works for me:

```
class A(val i: Int)

case class B(str: String, override val i:Int=1) extends A(i)

val b = B("test")
val b2 = b.copy(i = 2)
```

P.S. well technically you can just copy with no modifications and then edit `i` using reflection but this is not a great idea IMHO.

Comment: I cannot change the definition of B. How can it be done using reflection?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
val b2 = new B(b.str) { override val i = 2 }
```

The downside is that you have to re-construct `B` from the parameters which may be cumbersome if there are a lot of them.

Comment: That's not the only downside ... You may be surprised to find out for example, that `b == b2` is `true` or that `b2.copy().i` returns 1 ... and many more other fun facts like that :D